# Why does Python return 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ...' if the module is properly installed?

Tags: python, libraries, rdflib

I'm trying to import "rdflib" (`from rdflib import Graph`) for my Python code. For some reason, when I launch the code, the console returns me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rdflib'`. I run the same code a few months ago and it always worked, so I'm really annoyed about this error. I would be very grateful if you could help me!

The library is properly installed in the folder C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages, I've checked it manually (I've also tried to install again the library but nothing changes).

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Python 3.10.5

Comment: Have you checked the path variable using `import sys; print(sys.path())`?

Comment: I hadn't checked yet, but now I've solved the problem thanks to your suggestion. Thank you a lot!